# Circumvent cached images loaded from HTML5 FileSystem API

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-filesystem

I am saving images to the HTML5 filesystem using the [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).
Every n minutes I'm reloading and replacing these images from a server side method.

After each reload/replace cycle I'm showing these images on a website.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'filesystem://...';
```

But the image doesn't get updated on the website. When I open the filesystem url in a new tab I can see the changes.

I've added a "random" query parameter to the filesystem url

```
"&rnd=" + new Date().getTime();
```

but that doesn't circumvent the browser cache (I'm assuming that the problem is the browser cache, because in the Chrome Developer Tools in the Network tab says "(from cache)")

[image: "from cache" even with a query parameter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a test case for this question. To my surprise it worked as it should.
I guess that the last chrome update fixed this issue for me:

If someone wants to try this, have a look here:
http://test.joquery.com/cachedfilesystem/